# Problems With Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

when I click on the menu icon(it is possible only when the screen size is less than `576px`) visible at `575px`, it changes its place, and title(FOOD, LLC) also. How can I fix it?

Web Page:
https://muhammad1918.github.io/New-Menu/MenuSite/

Comment: please provide the code that is relevant to the question, instead of posting external links, also the question is really unclear: `when i click on this, it changes its place, and title(FOOD,LLC) also` this creates questions like: what was it suppost to do in the first place?

Comment: @RayeesAC Note that by copying that code here, you've changed the license of the code to CC-by-SA 4.0, which may not be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to absolute is the one choice :)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    h1 {font-size:10vw;}
    #second{
      position: absolute  !important;
      top: 40px;
      left: 40px;
    }
    .navbar{
      position: absolute !important;
      right: 0;
      top: 30px;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }
    #trois {
      margin-right:20px;
    }
    #first {
      position:relative !important;
    }
}
```

then  `position:relative !important;` to `#first` element.

Also add `ml-auto` class to menu button

`<button id="trois" class="navbar-toggler collapsed ml-auto">`

> **View Demo less than @576px window size to see the menu**

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you.But how can I get rid of those 30px from top of the window?

Answer (score 0):

This part:

Just remove the `margin-top`, and it will stay in the same line-height

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px)
h1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

If you want it to have the same padding on the sides (to not jump to the left) you have to add the padding manually since the default behaviour is to remove it. You need to add
`padding-left: 15px;` to the `.navbar-expand-sm>.container` at `@media (max-width: 575.98px)`. Since the default is 15px anyways when it's larger than that.